# No Results from Multi-property Projection Query in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-datastore, projection

I'm trying to query the database with:

```
fields = "property_1, property_2, ... property_n"  
query = "SELECT {0} FROM Table WHERE property_{n+1} = '{1}'".format(fields, property_{n+1})  
all_objs = CacheDatastore.fetch(query, refresh=True)
```

The problem is that the returned list is empty, while if the query is like

`"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE property_{n+1} ='{1}'"`, I receive the full set.
I've created the necessary indexes and have deployed them, so it is not from there.

The log says that a Blob key is not found, but none of the properties is different from `string`, `float` or `int`...

Comment: Need to see logs.  Hard to believe that `{n+1}` format syntax works, even with `Select *...`

Comment: The {n+1} is attempt at LaTeX grouping notation in order to underline that the property used in the WHERE part is not part of the SELECT list. Sorry if it leads to confusion. What would be the correct format in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned to be a bug in the db library which is no longer in development, so I'm leaving here the link to the ticket and the comments on it.
  GAE allows indexing of static members of the db.Model class hierarchy, but returns 0 results for projection queries where the static member is included
among the projected properties.
https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=119